# UIScrollView flexible layouts with AutoLayout

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, interface-builder, autolayout

I'm trying to achieve the following:
[image: 4 and 3.5 inch screens without scrollview]

The red view is a fixed height, pinned to the top of the screen. The blue view is a fixed height, pinned to the bottom of the screen. The green view has no defined height, and should expand/contract based on the available room (the width can stay the same).

This works great on 3.5 inch and 4 inch screens, until I add a UIScrollView into the mix. Once I add a UIScrollView, the green view will always keep its 4 inch screen size height, rather than contracting on 3.5 inch screens.

It ends up looking like this:
[image: 3.5 inch screen with scrollview]

I understand that UIScrollViews are treated differently in AutoLayout in order to allow scrolling, but what I can't figure out is how to use that to create the desired layout.

Comment: Please add screenshot with your constrains

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Huh, sods law. I spend a full day working on this and 10 minutes after posting it to StackOverflow I figure it out.

I cleared all of the constraints, and let Interface Builder add missing constraints automatically. I then pinned the Blue view's bottom vertical spacing to the Bottom Layout Guide, and set the green view's height constraint to be "Less Than or Equal To" rather than "Equal To".

[image: Screenshot of the constraints]